# Effective filter with small tap size

Tags: filters

I am dealing with a problem where I need to make a decision on a 500khz  signal under 100usec. The signal is noisy and I am detecting a peak in the incoming signal. Currently I do a 7 step mean filter (down sample by 7) and a moving average of 8 taps following that. This delays my signal 56 samples roughly 112 usec. (2 usec* 7 * 8) If I reduce the filter taps the noise starts to confuse my detector and it starts to fail. Noise is white Gaussian noise, there are no dominant frequencies in the noise.

I am not just interested in the presence of the peak (that would have been a simpler problem) but I am also interested in rise and fall time of the peak. The peak base duration could be between 50 samples (100uSec) to 5,000 samples (10msec). In slow cases the decision speed doesn't matter but in high speeds, the decision speed does make a difference.

My current detector is crude but very efficient. I basically look back filtered signals in time to see if certain thresholds are met or not to make a decision if there is a peak. Once I suspect there is a peak, I find the rise and fall time. This whole operation takes less than 50usec and very optimized. I loose another 100usec in time due to filter memory and I wanted to see if I could get a better detector design.

I have considered several options, such as derivative of the signal (gave up due to noise), matched filter (due to wide frequency range, difficult to design a filter that would work well etc.)

I am looking for ideas to optimize my decision time from its 150usec to 100usec range by reducing the filter delay but not impacting the filter quality.

Comment: Do you know anything about the characteristics of the noise ?

Comment: @PaulR I checked, there are no dominant frequencies in the noise, it appears it is voltage noise trickling into ADC. How would knowing the noise would help? I can do experiments.

Comment: What is 50 usec? Is it required time delay or is it length of your signal? What is length of your " special pattern in the incoming signal"?

Comment: Any information you have about the noise characteristics can help to design a better filter. Unfortunately "voltage noise trickling into ADC" doesn't tell us much. Can you plot a spectrum of the noise ? Is it stationary ? Do you have noise impulses (e.g. "shot noise") ?

Comment: It looks like your sampling rate is 500 kHz.  Is that correct? Do you know what frequency range your signal is in?

Comment: @SergV 50usec my allowance for decision making. Think of it this way, there is a perfect peak with nice rise and fall (gaussian shape), I need to determine 50usec after the skirt of the peak in real time. (i.e. the maximum allowed delay is 50usec)

Comment: @JimClay I know, I am trying to estimate a peak from 100Hz to 10Khz.

Comment: You need to clarify the problem. On the one hand you claim you're attempting to detect a pattern. Your most recent comment suggests your estimating a peak. These are two different problems. If it's a detection problem and your "special pattern" is well defined, then you want to look at what the optimal detector is. Most likely (most common noise/model assumptions), you'll be doing thresholding on matched filtering.

Comment: @bryan I didn't go for a matched filter since the signal amplitude and frequency is not known. I have a range for both but no exact figure at the time of detection. Moreover, I am not just interested in presence of a peak but the slopes of the peak.

Comment: @Ktuncer you're missing the forrest through the trees here. How can we answer your question when you add pertinent information with every comment? If you want an answer, edit your question to include the details you've given in the comments and as much additional detail about your problem and constraints as possible.

Comment: @Bryan done. I update the question with more details.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite very difficult to give a correct answer, because you do not give the full information. But I will try.
One of standard way is using "matching filter":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter

http://www.dspguide.com/ch17/3.htm

If length of your signal pattern is quite small (<50 usec) you can use this method.

Comment: I looked at matched filters. I have a pretty good idea how my signal looks like however I have a very wide range of frequencies I am detecting and this would require me to run the filter several times which would be prohibitively slow.